# Chart.js in ASP.NET, Data from database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web

I am currently working on the last page of my web form, which is the Dashboard. I followed this guide: http://www.sharepointblue.com/2015/01/using-chartsjs-with-aspnet.html?m=1 to implement chart.js graphs into my dashboard but it only shows me how to manually add data in. I am looking to have my axis and data points be pulled from the database. I've search around and just cant find out how to get the data directly from the database. If anyone could guide me in the right direction, that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use a call to an .ashx to retrieve the data in jSON, or you could even use a variable and construct the data and write it write into the data portion of the script.  I did that before and it worked, but it's not really the right way to do it.

Comment: Steve do you have something I can reference to get that done? Also what would be the "correct" way of doing it?

Comment: I just looked this up and haven't done exactly this, but this is the basic idea - It calls an ASP.Net Web Method via ajax to return the data: http://codepedia.info/2015/04/chartjs-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-database-calling-jquery-ajax-c/